Как правильно использовать Try Except для открытия файла на чтение-запись или только на чтение?
Пишу класс, который в конструкторе инициализируется из файла (обертка над данными в файле).
Файл нужно открывать на чтение и запись, если это возможно, а если нет, то только на чтение.
Правильно ли будет воспользоваться такой конструкцией:
    constructor TMyDocument.Create(const AFileName: string);
    begin
      try
        FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
        Load(FFile);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          if (E is EFOpenError) and (GetLastError = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) then
          try
            FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
            Load(FFile);
          except
            raise;
          end
          else
            raise;
      end;
    end;


Нет цели обработать исключение так, чтоб создать пустой объект в случае невозможности открыть файл, и завершить конструктор без ошибок. Обработать исключение - задача для того кто будет вызывать конструктор.
Есть ли смысл пробовать открыть файл через CreateFile() и обрабатывать код ошибки, или вполне приемлемо использовать TFileStream и try except? Дальнейшая загрузка идет через TStream.
Есть ли смысл во вложенном блоке try except (где идет попытка открыть файл только на чтение)? Или будет достаточно:

    constructor TMyDocument.Create(const AFileName: string);
    begin
      try
        FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
        Load(FFile);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          if (E is EFOpenError) and (GetLastError = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) then
          begin
            FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
            Load(FFile);
          end
          else
            raise;
      end;
    end;

--------- UPDATE -----------
По итогу пришел к вот такому решению:
constructor TMyDocument.Create(const AFileName: string);
begin
  try
    FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  except
    on E: EFOpenError do
      if (GetLastError = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) then
        FFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite)
      else
        raise;
  end;
  Load(FFile);
end;


Пустой except raise; достаточно бессмысленная конструкция. В остальном достаточно интересный вопрос, +1.

Подумав и посовещавшись, пришел к таким выводам: 1) вложенный try except лишний. 2) Нет смысла ловить все исключения, достаточно ловить только EFOpenError. 3) Непосредственно загрузку Load() следует вынести за блок try except.

По опыту, пару раз приходилось писать это дело в цикле, что-то типа "попробовать 3 раза", потому что бывало что-то держало файл при доступе и быстро отпускало (типа антивируса).

GetLastError тоже возвращал ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED? Я не сталкивался пока с таким случаем, буду иметь ввиду. Хотя, наверное, нет смысла рассматривать эту ситуацию в этом классе. Не смог открыть на запись - открываю на чтение. На чтение не смог - пусть разбирается тот, кто вызвал конструктор. Пусть хоть в цикле 10 раз попробует открыть.

Не по теме (возможно вы просто указали это для примера), но в конструкторах почти всегда стоит добавлять inherited Create. А если FFile это поле класса, а  Load метод того же класса, то не надо его дополнительно передавать в виде аргумента.

Этот конструктор имеет перезагруженный вариант загрузки из TStream. На самом деле там не Load(FFile), а Create(FFile) и вот уже в нем есть вызов конструктора предка.

GetLastError тут используется некорректно. Этот вызов должен идти сразу после вызова функции WinAPI.

Спасибо за помощь Kromster и user7860670.
Действительно, GetLastError после вызова TFileStream.Create() может вернуть 0 в зависимости от многих условий.
constructor TMyDocument.Create(const AFileName: string);
var
  tmpHandle: Integer;
begin
  tmpHandle := FileOpen(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  if (tmpHandle < 0) then
    if (GetLastError = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) then
    begin
      tmpHandle := FileOpen(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
      if (tmpHandle < 0) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    end
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  FFile := TFileStream.Create(tmpHandle);
  Load(FFile); // Create(FFile);
end;

Я счёл наиболее удачным решением отказаться от использования try except и создать TFileStream не через имя файла, а через handle, полученный через вызов CreateFile (в моём случае FileOpen - обертка из SysUtils).
